# connect to sql via windows authentication over vpn

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, vpn

Is there any way I can connect to a remote SQL server with Windows Authentication over VPN?

I can connect to the VPN server in Windows 7 using Domain Credentials like `\DOMAIN\user` but I want to be able to connect to the SQL server with the Domain Credentials because I don't have the `sa` account .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try creating a shortcut with:

```
runas /noprofile /netonly /user:domain\username ssms.exe
```

You may have to hard-code the path to ssms.exe. On modern versions, that's:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

In a few locations it will *look* in SSMS like you are using your local credentials, but you should be able to verify on the remote server that your credentials are being passed, e.g.

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME();
```

This of course depends on your requests being correctly routed to the destination SQL Server.

Comment: `runas` is a Windows built-in that allows you to run an executable in the guise of another user. You can read more here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas

Comment: Are you a wizard? Seriously though, that did the trick. Awesome little bit of functionality that I had no idea existed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the /noprofile /netonly otherwise you will get an error "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship."

Comment: Worked perfectly! I had to specify the file location, for most people this will be: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"