# "Login failed for user" error message when you log on to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have an issue where I am trying to connect to SQL SMS but using a different host name.

I have a hosts record for `127.0.0.1 win2012r2svr` and I can ping win2012r2svr and get 127.0.0.1 as the IP but I can't connect using that name in SMS.

The server name is win2k08r2svr and our live web server had the same name so I could use that in web.configs and other places to connect.  But I need connections made to win2012r2svr to work now since that is the name of our NEW web server.  It works fine from all the workstations but not from the server itself.

I know it's a bit convoluted but it's how I have it set up right now and it would be great if I could use either win2012r2svr or win2k08r2svr to connect.

Here is my setup:

[image: my setup]

Comment: Create a SQL Server Alias?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems self-explanatory - the server you're connecting to is not in the TRAKKWARE domain, and no appropriate trusts have been set up. This error message has nothing to do with being able to ping the other machine - I can ping all kinds of machines that aren't in my domain.

If you can't get help from your network / IT folks to set those trusts up (or put your workstation on that domain), you will need to to do one of the following:

- remote desktop to the server, and use SSMS there
- [use `runas /netonly` and supply appropriate domain credentials in that server's domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672170/61305)
- use SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication

Also, if the server has changed names, it would be useful to outline the process that you took, but the error you're currently getting doesn't seem to be a name resolution problem, but rather a cross-domain problem.

(And if the server has changed names, you should either add an alias in DNS, or just update the connection strings in your apps. If the server name is hard-coded in the compiled code in your apps, this is a perfect opportunity to change them and stop doing that.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is that there is no other server.  This is an alias on the same server.  I can't set up a domain trust as there is no box with that name to actually connect to.  It is the same box but I want a different name to work while connecting.

Using SQL authentication DOES get around this but I want to be able to connect with integrated security.

Comment: To reiterate in a simpler way, I need to be able to use a different computer name in a connection string to connect to SQL.  From workstations connecting to this server I set up HOSTS file info with the IP of the server and I can connect using integrated auth with no problem.  The HOSTS file knows the IP of the server and then the server knows the user and it's all good.  From the server itself, though, I am having issues.  I set up a HOSTS record there too with 127.0.0.1 but then I get that error.

Comment: Pinging was to show that the host name was recognized by the server but unfortunately SQL won't let me in :-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a [SQL Server alias](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/) name for win2012r2svr.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, right-click on Aliases and choose New Alias, then set:
AliasName= win2012r2svr
Server = 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to work