# Remotely connect to SQL Server (ODBC) using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-authentication, vpn, navision

We are trying to connect to our SQL server via VPN which is the server using Windows Authentication (Domain user)

It works well when we are in the office. When we later connect with VPN it will not work. Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

When we are connected via VPN we can ping both SQL Server and the Domain Controller, but unable to connect using Windows Authentication ... 
In contrast, if we log in with regular Database login, it works.

Is there any port we need to open? Is there some setting on the SQL server and / or domain controller that must be done in order to use Windows Authentication from a different subnet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try the solution from The following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671904/connect-to-sql-via-windows-authentification-over-vpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its some-thing not clear about when you are able to connect and not connect. Via office lan you able to connect VPN and sqlserver with window auth. But later means?.

Answer is When we use VPN, at the same time we have option to use window or sqlserver. But we direct connect without VPN, we are not in their lan and that's why we are not connect with window auth, we must connect with sqlserver mode only with permission user(s).