# Opening SQL Server Management Studio as different user automatically with run or runas commands

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying open SQL Server Management Studio as different user than that I am logged in as in the below command but SQL Server Management Studio is opening but not as the User DevAdminAm, it is just opening like my login user not as different user

```
runas.exe /noprofile /netonly /user:XXXXXtrs\DevAdminAm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

Can anybody please help me why is it not opening when I save it as batch file and double click it or when I run it as windows command in the startup.

When I run it in startup, it opens SSMS but not as different user as I am intending, any help please.

Comment: What specifically makes you think it's not opening as a different user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. Try to set in your credentials manager with these credentials:

- **Server:** `servername.tld:1433`
- **User:** `domain\account`
- **Password:** Password of the user `domain\account`

Comment: What is iId in it and what is 1433, how can I get those details for my Database Server?

Comment: Ehy Abdul, tld is the top level domain, it's mean that if you server is server u have to declare server.domain.com. 1433 is the SQL server default port, try to have a netstat -ano | findstr -i listen

Answer (score 1):

The UI will show you your currently logged in local user, e.g. in the connection dialog and Object Explorer, but when you are connected to the server and run `SELECT SUSER_SNAME();`, it will show your specified domain account.

See [the explanation about that here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and also mentioned several places here, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672170/61305).